# bash: ./main.o cannot execute binary file Exec format error

Tags: c++, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have set up a ubuntu virtual machine on windows using virtual box.

I am trying to run a C++ project. The make file looks like this

```
CC = g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated 

tag = -i

ifdef linux
tag = -n
endif

test.out: Record.o Comparison.o ComparisonEngine.o Schema.o File.o DBFile.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o test.o
    $(CC) -o test.out Record.o Comparison.o ComparisonEngine.o Schema.o File.o DBFile.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o test.o -lfl

main: Record.o Comparison.o ComparisonEngine.o Schema.o File.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o main.o
    $(CC) -o main Record.o Comparison.o ComparisonEngine.o Schema.o File.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o main.o -lfl

test.o: test.cc
    $(CC) -g -c test.cc

main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) -g -c main.cc

Comparison.o: Comparison.cc
    $(CC) -g -c Comparison.cc

ComparisonEngine.o: ComparisonEngine.cc
    $(CC) -g -c ComparisonEngine.cc

DBFile.o: DBFile.cc
    $(CC) -g -c DBFile.cc

File.o: File.cc
    $(CC) -g -c File.cc

Record.o: Record.cc
    $(CC) -g -c Record.cc

Schema.o: Schema.cc
    $(CC) -g -c Schema.cc

y.tab.o: Parser.y
    yacc -d Parser.y
    sed $(tag) y.tab.c -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ ((__unused__));\n# endif/" 
    g++ -c y.tab.c

lex.yy.o: Lexer.l
    lex  Lexer.l
    gcc  -c lex.yy.c

clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.out
    rm -f y.tab.c
    rm -f lex.yy.c
    rm -f y.tab.h
```

After running the make command I get a bunch of warnings like

```
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c Record.cc
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c Comparison.cc
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c ComparisonEngine.cc
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c Schema.cc
Schema.cc: In constructor ‘Schema::Schema(const char*, const char*)’:
Schema.cc:46:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:58:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:84:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:91:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:95:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:106:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:114:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Schema.cc:118:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fscanf (foo, "%s", space);
   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c File.cc
File.cc: In member function ‘void File::GetPage(Page*, off_t)’:
File.cc:186:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (myFilDes, bits, PAGE_SIZE);
  ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File.cc: In member function ‘void File::AddPage(Page*, off_t)’:
File.cc:206:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    write (myFilDes, &foo, sizeof (int));
    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File.cc:223:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  write (myFilDes, bits, PAGE_SIZE);
  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File.cc: In member function ‘void File::Open(int, char*)’:
File.cc:258:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   read (myFilDes, &curLength, sizeof (off_t));
   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File.cc: In member function ‘int File::Close()’:
File.cc:276:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  write (myFilDes, &curLength, sizeof (off_t));
  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c DBFile.cc
yacc -d Parser.y
sed -i y.tab.c -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ ((__unused__));\n# endif/" 
g++ -c y.tab.c
y.tab.c: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
y.tab.c:1427:35: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
                                   ^
y.tab.c:1571:35: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   yyerror (YY_("memory exhausted"));
                                   ^
lex  Lexer.l
gcc  -c lex.yy.c
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -g -c test.cc
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated  -o test.out Record.o Comparison.o ComparisonEngine.o Schema.o File.o DBFile.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o test.o -lfl
```

All files compile generating respective `.o` files except the `main.cc`. So I compile it using this command

```
g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated -g -c -o main.o main.cc
```

Now the `main.o` file compiles and main.o is generated

I then run it using `./main.o` and get **Permission denied**

So I get rid of this error by `chmod 755 ./*`
Now running the `main.o` gives this error

```
bash: ./main.o cannot execute binary file Exec format error
```

Through my research I found out that this error is because of the mismatch in arhitecture and file type.

`file main.o` outputs **x86-64** and `uname -m` outputs **x86_64**

I cannot figure out the problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: *"I then run it using `./main.o`"* - that's just object code, not an executable. When you said, *"So I compile it using this command:"* - do you know what that command *does* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute an object file. Object files like `main.o` are not executable. They only contain part of the code required to form an exectuable.

You need to run `main` (or maybe `test.out`), which is the actual executable.

The permission warnings were telling you the same thing (that `main.o` is not executable), but you overwrote that with `chmod`.

`main` should be created by `make` assuming there are no compilation/linking errors if you use `make main` or `test.out` if you use `make` or `make test.out`. The linker invocation is given in the `main:`/`test.out:` target of the Makefile. If `make` generates compiler or linker errors, then repeating the same commands manually is not going to fix it. Fix the code or Makefile instead.

Also note that the warnings/errors are there for a reason. Since C++11, you are not allowed to cast string literals to `char*`, only to `const char*`. This was deprecated already in C++03. Circumventing that rule is only going to cause you trouble in the future. Fix your code instead of adding `-Wno-deprecated`.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing out a lot of things. It was really helpful. I have added the errors I get after the running the make file if you'd like to comment on that.

I have never really done a c++ project before. This code is actually given by my professor as a starter code. And I have to do a project on top of this. So trying to setup the project now.

Comment: @DeepBodra There are no errors, only warnings. The build was sucessful and the executable `test.out` was built. You can run that. If you want to build `main` instead, you need to call `make main`. I fixed my answer. Whether you are supposed to built and execute `main` or `test.out`, I don't know.

Comment: @DeepBodra Based on the warning messages the compiler is giving, the code you got from your professor is bad and is not going to work with newer C++ versions. All of these warnings should have been fixed and using `fscanf` (a C library function) in C++ which has its own input/output library is also not a good sign.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try fixing the code instead. I love this community! By the way, is it possible to switch to a older version of the g++ compiler to get around this problem?

Comment: @DeepBodra You can always add the `-std=c++98`/`-std=c++03` flag to the compiler if it complains that the code uses something that was removed from the language. But that is obviously not a nice solution, given that it makes it impossible to use newer language features.